# Check for 3G support on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, 3g, reachability

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check network type in iPhone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021172/how-to-check-network-type-in-iphone-app)

I would like to know how I can check for 3G support on the iPhone. I checked the latest Reachability code and it doesn't include any code for checking the 3g availability.

Comment: The first answer here might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023404/can-i-prevent-iphone-from-using-3g-under-any-circumstances

Comment: Why did you remove the iphone tag I added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean 3G vs Edge connectivity? Or the existence of 3G?

This should point you in the right direction: kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsIsWWAN
"@constant kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsIsWWAN
        This flag indicates that the specified nodename or address can
        be reached via an EDGE, GPRS, or other "cell" connection."

If you could be more specific, we can be more help.

Comment: Existence of 3G/Edge Connection